# Azure CLI task doesn't work on Windows build agents

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-container-instances

I've created an Azure DevOps task group to create a selenium container on Azure (Azure container instance) as follows:

[image: Azure container task group]

Script:

```
ipAddress="$(az container create  \
-g $(resourceGroup) \
--name temp-$(ContainerName) \
--image myregistry.azurecr.io/selenium/standalone-chrome \
--cpu 2 \
--memory 4 \
--os-type Linux \
--ports 4444 \
--vnet $(VNet)
--subnet $(Subnet)
--registry-username $(registryUsername) \
--registry-password $(registryPassword) \
--environment-variables \
NODE_MAX_SESSION=10 \
Browser=$(Browser) \
--query 'ipAddress.ip' -o tsv)"

echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$(SeleniumHubVariable);]http://$ipAddress:4444/wd/hub/"
```

This task is executed successfully when running on a Linux build agent.

When I try to run it on a Windows build agent the task doesn't fail but the container is not created. Output of the task is the following:

> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>ipAddress="$(az container create  \ 
>   'ipAddress' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>-g myresourcegroup \ 
>   '-g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>--name temp-1807-build-385769 \ 
>   '--name' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>--image mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/selenium/standalone-chrome \ 
>   '--image' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>--cpu 2 \ 
>   '--cpu' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>--memory 4 \ 
>   '--memory' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   '--os-type' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>--os-type Linux \
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>--ports 4444 \ 
>   '--ports' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>--vnet ..... \ 
>   '--vnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>--subnet .... \ 
>   '--subnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>--registry-username myregistryusername \ 
>   '--registry-username' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>--registry-password *** \ 
>   '--registry-password' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>--environment-variables \ 
>   '--environment-variables' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>NODE_MAX_SESSION=10 \ 
>   'NODE_MAX_SESSION' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>Browser=$(Browser) \ 
>   'Browser' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> F:\Agent03\w\125\s>--query 'ipAddress.ip' -o tsv)" 
>   '--query' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

What am I missing? How can I make it work for both Windows and Linux?

Comment: Windows is not the same as Linux and the Azure CLI is more suitable for Linux. You change the command into PowerShell. Or you can try to change the "\" into "`", the back quote.

Comment: @CharlesXu that might help but unfortunately it's not enough to fix the issue - I've tried removing all backslashes and put the first command in a single line but I still get a warning: `ipAddress is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`

Comment: Yeah, in windows. You should use the set to create a variable, just like `set variable_name=value`. And it's different in CMD and PowerShell. In PowerShell, you can create the variable like `$variable_name=value`. You can try the PowerShell way first.

Comment: @CharlesXu I was able to find a solution for my problem, but anyway thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am now able to make it work with Windows agents, using 2 tasks.

### Task 1 (Azure CLI) - Create the container instance and output of the command (IP address) to a file

[image: Create container instance (Windows)]

Script:

```
az container create ^
-g $(resourceGroup) ^
--name temp-$(ContainerName) ^
--image myregistry.azurecr.io/selenium/standalone-chrome ^
--cpu 2 ^
--memory 4 ^
--os-type Linux ^
--ports 4444 ^
--vnet $(VNet)
--subnet $(Subnet)
--registry-username $(registryUsername) ^
--registry-password $(registryPassword) ^
--environment-variables ^
NODE_MAX_SESSION=10 ^
Browser=$(Browser) ^
--query "ipAddress.ip" -o tsv>tmpFile-$(ContainerName).txt
```

Some notes:

- `\` characters were replaced with `^`
- Single quotes works fine on Linux (`--query 'ipAddress.ip'`) but on Windows I had to use double quotes (`--query "ipAddress.ip"`)

### Task 2 (Powershell) - Read the IP address from the file and set the environment variable

```
$ipAddress = [IO.File]::ReadAllText("tmpFile-$(ContainerName).txt")

Write-Host "Selenium hub URL is http://$($ipAddress.Trim()):4444/wd/hub/"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$(SeleniumHubVariable);]http://$($ipAddress.Trim()):4444/wd/hub/"
```

### Setting custom conditions for the tasks

Unfortunately I had to create different versions of the tasks for each OS (Windows or Linux):

[image: Task list]

To run these tasks depending on the OS of the build agent you can set custom conditions:

[image: Custom conditions]

So, to run a task on a Windows build agent you can set this custom condition:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Windows_NT'))
```

To run it on a Linux build agent:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Linux'))
```

PS: `Agent.OS` can be found on the build agent capabilities